# bzr - create tgz file containing full repository

Tags: backup, bazaar

I'm trying to backup my shared bzr repository. I have looked at `bzr export hotcopy.tgz` but it seems only to take a snapshot of the latest revision.

Is there a command for doing backups, or do I have to

1. full checkout into a tmp dir
2. compress the tmp dir
3. remove the tmp dir

Or is there a better way to backup a bzr repository?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could try something like this:

```
mkdir /tmp/emptyrepos && bzr init /tmp/emptyrepos && bzr send -r 1..last:1 -o - /tmp/emptyrepos | gzip > mybackup.bzr.gz
```

That will create a bazaar native format merge-directive which you could apply to an empty repository to re-create all state.

Alternatively, it's likely safe to just tar up the current checkout.  The on-disk format should be designed to safely deal with partial updates you may grab with tar.

Comment: When running this command, I'm experiencing this: ERROR: Not a branch: "/private/tmp/".

I'm on Mac OS X. The I have tried inserting /private/tmp, but it gives same error. I'm new to bazaar so I don't quite understand the error message yet.

Comment: The basic idea is to create an empty branch to diff against - you can make an empty directory somewhere and run bzr init within it; I just used something in /tmp/ because it's a good place to put temporary stuff.  That said, are you sure you didn't mistype it?

Comment: Here is the terminal output http://pastebin.im/1408  Thank you very much, but I think I go for the checkout temporary repository instead of using send, since it seems more simple.

Comment: Just as a note, to restore a branch backed up in this way, you need to do "bzr init ." then "bzr pull <merge_directive_file_>". Merging into an empty branch is currently not supported (bug https://bugs.launchpad.net/bzr/+bug/82555) but pulling the merge directive will work. Just be sure to extract the merge directive from the .gz file, or else it will say it is not a branch.

Comment: 'bzr send' is slow, not optimized for size, and not tuned to be used for entire repositories. Creating a temporary standalone branch without a tree (" bzr branch --no-tree") is the best way to create the data you need to back up.